# iOS 4.x: UIWebView iframe Scrolling

Tags: iframe, uiwebview, ios4

I'm using a UIWebView to show an html page with an iframe in it.

The UIWebView has myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

and the page itself has

<meta name="viewport" content="width=320,user-scalable=yes"/>

Under 3.2 , the iframe had very nice scrollbars and I could scale and double tap the contents of the iframe, which is a javascript-dynamically loaded PDF. Under 4.x , it's not interactive at all and has no scrollbars. Yes, this is the same code.

I'm not aware of any new flags for this behavior under 4.x. Are you? Or will I have to end up making a UITextView and loading the PDF there?

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion on a duplicate question someone asked later, and in light of Apple's own [documentation stating this should be possible](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1484), it sounds like this is a (annoying) bug in recent versions of iOS:
[IFRAMEs and the Safari on the iPad, how can the user scroll the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599153/iframes-and-the-safari-on-the-ipad-how-can-the-user-scroll-the-content)

I've filed rdar://problem/8904584 with Apple, if this is affecting you please (everyone) file a duplicate at http://bugreport.apple.com referencing that bug number.

Comment: I'll join that bug, even though I ended up having to make a TextView for it (a few months ago).