# IFRAMEs and the Safari on the iPad, how can the user scroll the content?

Tags: html, ipad, iframe, safari, scroll

According to the Apple iOS mantra it should be possible to scroll the contents of an IFRAME by dragging it with two fingers.  Unfortunately running the latest version of iOS on the iPad I have yet to find a single website with an IFRAME that scrolls using this method - no scrollbars appear either.

Does anyone know how a user is supposed to scroll the contents of an IFRAME with the mobile Safari?

Comment: I have had no problem with using 2 fingers. No scroll bars appear, but the content scrolls.

Comment: Please migrate the question to superuser, and post an example site that does not work. Two-finger scrolling works on every site I have tried with my iPad.

Comment: It certainly does not work with the latest version of iOS (4.2.1) try the w3 site example:  

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

Compare how the page looks on the iPad and a desktop browser.  Completely different and no scrolling possible.

This is a programming question as it is a question of what style bits need to be set on the IFRAME or a surrounding DIV for the scrolling to work.

Comment: See [How to properly display an iFrame in Mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267996/how-to-properly-display-an-iframe-in-mobile-safari).

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios

Answer (score 89, accepted):

iOS 5 added the following style that can be added to the parent div so that scrolling works.

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch`

Comment: I found that I have to add this as a style on the parent div. If I set it using `jQuery("#div").css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling","touch")` then it doesn't actually work. Also, you now have to combine it with `overflow:auto` which means you *might* get double scrollbars on some non-touch browsers...

Comment: The following jQuery sugar works for me: https://gist.github.com/2388015  (this is very basic and doesn't implement border copying)

Comment: Does it work with ChromeApp on iPad? It works at Safari Mobile

Comment: Works here in iOS 7.  Did it work before on your end in IOS 6?

Answer (score 24):

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` as mentioned in the answer is infact the possible solution.

```
<div style="overflow:scroll !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;">
     <iframe src="YOUR_PAGE_URL" width="600" height="400"></iframe>
</div>
```

But if you are unable to scroll up and down inside the iframe as shown in image below,
[image]

you could try scrolling with 2 fingers diagonally like this,

[image]

This actually worked in my case, so just sharing it if you haven't still found a solution for this.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't appear that iframes display and scroll properly. You can use an object tag to replace an iframe and the contents will be scrollable with 2 fingers. Here's a simple example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=false; initial-scale=1.0;"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>HEADER - use 2 fingers to scroll contents:</div>
        <div id="scrollee" style="height:75%;" >
            <object id="object" height="90%" width="100%" type="text/html" data="http://en.wikipedia.org/"></object>
        </div>
        <div>FOOTER</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either.  It seems that two fingered iframe and object scrolling broke in 4.2.1 (although it works for textboxes).  Hopefully Apple will fix this annoying bug in the next release.

Comment: Anyone how a valid source on this bug? Like from Apple?

Answer (score 7):

This is not my answer, but I just copied it from https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2388015 just because the answer is awesome and fixes the problem completely. Credit completely goes to the anonymous author.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if (/iPhone|iPod|iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent))
            $('iframe').wrap(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                return $('<div />').css({
                    width: $this.attr('width'),
                    height: $this.attr('height'),
                    overflow: 'auto',
                    '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch'
                });
            });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in other posts, the combination of css values of overflow: auto; & 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

works when applied to BOTH the iframe in question AND its parent div

With the unfortunate side-effect of double scrollbars on non-touch browsers.

The solution I used was to add these css values via javascript/jquery. Which allowed me to use a base css for all browsers

```
if (isSafariBrowser()){
    $('#parentDivID').css('overflow', 'auto');
    $('#parentDivID').css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling', 'touch');
    $('#iframeID').css('overflow', 'auto');
    $('#iframeID').css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling', 'touch');
}
```

where isSafariBrowser() is defined as foll...

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
var is_safari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;

function isSafariBrowser(){
    if (is_safari){
        if (is_chrome)  // Chrome seems to have both Chrome and Safari userAgents
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This allowed my application to work on an iPad 
Note
1) Not tested on other ios systems
2) Not tested this on Android browsers on tablets, may need additional changes

(so this solution may not be complete)

Comment: `function isSafariBrowser() { return is_safari && !is_chrome; }` Besides the fact you don't need a function for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to get iframe scrolling to work on iPad. Note that this solution only works if you control the html that is displayed inside the iframe.

It actually turns off the default iframe scrolling, and instead causes the body tag inside the iframe to scroll.

**main.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#iframe {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <iframe src="test.html" id="iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**test.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html { 
    overflow: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
…
</body>
</html>
```

The same could probably be accomplished using jQuery if you prefer:

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("body").css({
    "height": "100%",
    "overflow": "auto", 
    "-webkit-overflow-scrolling": "touch"
});
```

I used this solution to get TinyMCE (wordpress editor) to scroll properly on the iPad.

Comment: You're jquery should have commas instead of semi-colons. Otherwise this seems good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The code below works for me (thanks to Christopher Zimmermann for his blog post http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/blog/2012/05/strategies-for-the-iframe-on-the-ipad-problem/). The problems are:

1. There are no scroll bars to let the user know that they can scroll
2. Users have to use two-finger scrolling
3. The PDF files are not centered (still working on it)

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>Testing iFrames on iPad</title>
     <style>
     div {
       border: solid 1px green;
       height:100px;
     }

   .scroller{
       border:solid 1px #66AA66;
       height: 400px;
       width: 400px;
       overflow: auto;
       text-align:center;

   }
   </style>
   ```

   ```
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><div class="scroller">
       <iframe width="400" height="400" src="http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/11pdf/11-393c3a2.pdf" ></iframe>
   </div>
       </td>
       <td><div class="scroller">
       <iframe width="400" height="400" src="http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/11pdf/11-393c3a2.pdf" ></iframe>
   </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><div class="scroller">
       <iframe width="400" height="400" src="http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/11pdf/11-393c3a2.pdf" ></iframe>
   </div>
       </td>
       <td><div class="scroller">
       <iframe width="400" height="400" src="http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/11pdf/11-393c3a2.pdf" ></iframe>
   </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <div> Here are some additional contents.</div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/11/26/pdf-scrolling-on-ipad), I have put together the following snippet that provides some very basic functionality:

```
<div id = "container"></div>
<script>
function setPDFHeight(){ 
        $("#pdfObject")[0].height = $("#pdfObject")[0].offsetHeight;   
}   
$('#container').append('<div align="center" style="width: 100%; height:100%; overflow: auto !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;">\
      <object id="pdfObject" width="100%" height="1000000000000" align="center" data="content/lessons/12/t.pdf" type="application/pdf" onload="setPDFHeight()">You have no plugin installed</object></div>');  
</script>
```

Obviously it is far from perfect (given that it practically expands your page height to infinity), but it's the only viable workaround I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions so far completely worked for me when I tried (sometimes, only buggy on secondary loads), but as a workaround, using an object element as described here, then wrapping in a scrollable div, then setting the object to a very high height (5000px) did the job for me. It's a big workaround and doesn't work incredibly well (for starters, pages over 5000px would cause issues -- 10000px completely broke it for me though) but it seems to get the job done in some of my test cases:

```
var style = 'left: ...px; top: ...px; ' +
        'width: ...px; height: ...px; border: ...';

if (isIOs) {
    style += '; overflow: scroll !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;';
    html = '<div style="' + style + '">' +
           '<object type="text/html" data="http://example.com" ' +
           'style="width: 100%; height: 5000px;"></object>' +
           '</div>';
}
else {
    style += '; overflow: auto;';
    html = '<iframe src="http://example.com" ' +
           'style="' + style + '"></iframe>';
}
```

Here's hoping Apple will fix the Safari iFrame issues.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

I help maintain a big, complicated, messy old site in which *everything* (literally) is nested in multiple levels of iframes-- many of which are dynamically created and/or have a dynamic src. That creates the following challenges:

1. Any changes to the HTML structure risk breaking scripts and stylesheets that haven't been touched in years.
2. Finding and fixing all of the iframes and src documents manually would take way too much time and effort.

Of the solutions posted so far, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24779451/2759272) is the only one I've seen that overcomes challenge 1. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work on some iframes, and when it does, the scrolling is very glitchy (which seems to cause other bugs on the page, such as unresponsive links and form controls).

**The Solution**

If the above sounds anything like your situation, you may want to give the following script a try. It forgoes native scrolling and instead makes all iframes draggable within the bounds of their viewport. You only need to add it to the document that contains the top level iframes; it will apply the fix as needed to them and their descendants.

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftsL1fde/)*, and here's the code:

```
(function() {
  var mouse = false //Set mouse=true to enable mouse support
    , iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);
  if(mouse || iOS) {
    (function() {
      var currentFrame
        , startEvent, moveEvent, endEvent
        , screenY, translateY, minY, maxY
        , matrixPrefix, matrixSuffix
        , matrixRegex = /(.*([\.\d-]+, ?){5,13})([\.\d-]+)(.*)/
        , min = Math.min, max = Math.max
        , topWin = window;
      if(!iOS) {
        startEvent = 'mousedown';
        moveEvent = 'mousemove';
        endEvent = 'mouseup';
      }
      else {
        startEvent = 'touchstart';
        moveEvent = 'touchmove';
        endEvent = 'touchend';
      }
      setInterval(scrollFix, 500);
      function scrollFix() {fixSubframes(topWin.frames);}
      function fixSubframes(wins) {for(var i = wins.length; i; addListeners(wins[--i]));}
      function addListeners(win) {
        try {
          var doc = win.document;
          if(!doc.draggableframe) {
            win.addEventListener('unload', resetFrame);
            doc.draggableframe = true;
            doc.addEventListener(startEvent, touchStart);
            doc.addEventListener(moveEvent, touchMove);
            doc.addEventListener(endEvent, touchEnd);
          }
          fixSubframes(win.frames);
        }
        catch(e) {}
      }
      function resetFrame(e) {
        var doc = e.target
          , win = doc.defaultView
          , iframe = win.frameElement
          , style = getComputedStyle(iframe).transform;
        if(iframe===currentFrame) currentFrame = null;
        win.removeEventListener('unload', resetFrame);
        doc.removeEventListener(startEvent, touchStart);
        doc.removeEventListener(moveEvent, touchMove);
        doc.removeEventListener(endEvent, touchEnd);
        if(style !== 'none') {
          style = style.replace(matrixRegex, '$1|$3|$4').split('|');
          iframe.style.transform = style[0] + 0 + style[2];
        }
        else iframe.style.transform = null;
        iframe.style.WebkitClipPath = null;
        iframe.style.clipPath = null;
        delete doc.draggableiframe;
      }
      function touchStart(e) {
        var iframe, style, offset, coords
          , touch = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e
          , elem = touch.target
          , tag = elem.tagName;
        currentFrame = null;
        if(tag==='TEXTAREA' || tag==='SELECT' || tag==='HTML') return;
        for(;elem.parentElement; elem = elem.parentElement) {
          if(elem.scrollHeight > elem.clientHeight) {
            style = getComputedStyle(elem).overflowY;
            if(style==='auto' || style==='scroll') return;
          }
        }
        elem = elem.ownerDocument.body;
        iframe = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView.frameElement;
        coords = getComputedViewportY(elem.clientHeight < iframe.clientHeight ? elem : iframe);
        if(coords.elemTop >= coords.top && coords.elemBottom <= coords.bottom) return;
        style = getComputedStyle(iframe).transform;
        if(style !== 'none') {
          style = style.replace(matrixRegex, '$1|$3|$4').split('|');
          matrixPrefix = style[0];
          matrixSuffix = style[2];
          offset = parseFloat(style[1]);
        }
        else {
          matrixPrefix = 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ';
          matrixSuffix = ')';
          offset = 0;
        }
        translateY = offset;
        minY = min(0, offset - (coords.elemBottom - coords.bottom));
        maxY = max(0, offset + (coords.top - coords.elemTop));
        screenY = touch.screenY;
        currentFrame = iframe;
      }
      function touchMove(e) {
        var touch, style;
        if(currentFrame) {
          touch = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
          style = min(maxY, max(minY, translateY + (touch.screenY - screenY)));
          if(style===translateY) return;
          e.preventDefault();
          currentFrame.contentWindow.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
          translateY = style;
          currentFrame.style.transform = matrixPrefix + style + matrixSuffix;
          style = 'inset(' + (-style) + 'px 0px ' + style + 'px 0px)';
          currentFrame.style.WebkitClipPath = style;
          currentFrame.style.clipPath = style;
          screenY = touch.screenY;
        }
      }
      function touchEnd() {currentFrame = null;}
      function getComputedViewportY(elem) {
        var style, offset
          , doc = elem.ownerDocument
          , bod = doc.body
          , elemTop = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + elem.clientTop
          , elemBottom = elem.clientHeight
          , viewportTop = elemTop
          , viewportBottom = elemBottom + elemTop
          , position = getComputedStyle(elem).position;
        try {
          while(true) {
            if(elem === bod || position === 'fixed') {
              if(doc.defaultView.frameElement) {
                elem = doc.defaultView.frameElement;
                position = getComputedStyle(elem).position;
                offset = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + elem.clientTop;
                viewportTop += offset;
                viewportBottom = min(viewportBottom + offset, elem.clientHeight + offset);
                elemTop += offset;
                doc = elem.ownerDocument;
                bod = doc.body;
                continue;
              }
              else break;
            }
            else {
              if(position === 'absolute') {
                elem = elem.offsetParent;
                style = getComputedStyle(elem);
                position = style.position;
                if(position === 'static') continue;
              }
              else {
                elem = elem.parentElement;
                style = getComputedStyle(elem);
                position = style.position;
              }
              if(style.overflowY !== 'visible') {
                offset = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + elem.clientTop;
                viewportTop = max(viewportTop, offset);
                viewportBottom = min(viewportBottom, elem.clientHeight + offset);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        catch(e) {}
        return {
          top: max(viewportTop, 0)
          ,bottom: min(viewportBottom, doc.defaultView.innerHeight)
          ,elemTop: elemTop
          ,elemBottom: elemBottom + elemTop
        };
      }
    })();
  }
})();
```

* The jsfiddle has mouse support enabled for testing purposes. On a production site, you'd want to set mouse=false.

Answer (score -1):

After much aggravation, I discovered how to scroll in iframes on my ipad.  The secret was to do a vertical finger swipe (single finger was fine) on the LEFT side of the iframe area (and maybe slightly outside of the border).  On a laptop or PC, the scroll bar is on the right, so naturally, I spent of lot of time on my ipad experimenting with finger motions on the right side. Only when I tried the left side would the iframe scroll.

Answer (score -1):

Add `overflow: auto;` to the style and the two finger scroll should work.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately.  The correct answer is marked above.

Comment: you have to use both to target older and newer iPads or people not on the latest iOS