# sencha touch :: how to create a panel for website-preview inside iFrame

Tags: iframe, sencha-touch, preview

I need to allow some website previews inside sencha touch. I see two different possibilities:

1. opening safariMobile-app to show the link
2. generating a panel with an iFrame inside the 'html'-property.

because I don't know how to achieve 1. I started with 2. but run into some trouble:

a) the content of my iFrameis not scrollable. if I try to scroll the content, the whole viewport scrolls, including my bottom-tabPanel-Buttons!

b) the displayed website seems to load without any css or images

here is my previewPanel-code:

```
app.views.WebsitePreview = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    layout: 'card',
    scroll: 'vertical',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    fullscreen: true,

    initComponent: function(){      
        this.html = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="'+ this.theLink + '"></iframe>',
        var toolbarBase = {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Vorschau ' //+ this.childData.childUsername,
        };


        if (this.prevCard !== undefined) {
                toolbarBase.items = [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                        ui: 'back',
                    text: 'zurück', //this.prevCard.title,
                    scope: this,
                    handler: function(){
                        this.baseScope.setActiveItem(this.prevCard, { type: 'slide', reverse: true });
                    }
                }
            ]
       };

        this.dockedItems = toolbarBase;
        app.views.WebsitePreview.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});

Ext.reg('websitepreview', app.views.WebsitePreview);
```

thnx for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent two days fighting with the same problem. It seems that finally I found a solution.

The first thing you should try is to use new built-in feature introduced in iOS 5.

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

You need to wrap your iframe with div, something like:

```
...
this.html = '<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; height: 500px; overflow: auto;"><iframe .../></div>'
...
```

If it doesn't work (in my case it worked only first time) then you can try to handle touch events by yourself. Let's say you have the following structure in html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <iframe id="my-iframe" .../>
</div>
```

to make iframe scrollable you need to add this JS

```
var startY = 0;
var startX = 0;
var ifrDocument = document.getElementById("my-iframe").contentWindow.document;
ifrDocument.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    startY = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;
    startX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
});
ifrDocument.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var posy = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;
    var h = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    var sty = h.scrollTop;

    var posx = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
    var stx = h.scrollLeft;
    h.scrollTop = sty - (posy - startY);
    h.scrollLeft = stx - (posx - startX);
    startY = posy;
    startX = posx;
});
```

Source of the second solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359546)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I got this to work was by nesting the `<iframe>` in 2 panels, but this will probably only work if you know the dimensions of the document in the `<iframe>`, I also placed a transparent `<div>` over the `<iframe>` so the touch events still trigger the "scroll events"

```
root = new Ext.Panel({
   fullscreen: true,
   layout: 'card',
   version: '1.1.1',
   scroll: false,
   dockedItems: [{ xtype: 'toolbar', title: 'hello'}],
   items: [{
       xtype: 'panel',
       scroll: 'both',
       items: [{
           id: 'iframe',
           layout: 'vbox',
           width: '1200px',
           height: '1000px',
           html: ['<div style="width:1200px;height:1000px;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;background-color:Transparent;float:left;z-index:99;"></div>',
                  '<iframe style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;float:left;z-index:1;" width="1200px" height="1000px" src="http://google.com/"></iframe>']
       }]
    }]
});
```

So using your code:

```
this.items = [{
               id: 'iframe',
               layout: 'vbox',
               width: '1200px',
               height: '1000px',
               html: ['<div style="width:1200px;height:1000px;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;background-color:Transparent;float:left;z-index:99;"></div>',
                      '<iframe style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;float:left;z-index:1;" width="1200px" height="1000px" src="' this.theLink + '"></iframe>']
           }]
```

Comment: It does scroll, but the iframe content out of the viewport can not render when I scroll down.

Comment: use sencha touch 2.0 it might have fixed this issue