# How to prevent scroll lag on Safari Mobile (iPad)?

Tags: ipad, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I have a simple html5 page with 3 divs inside. If I only allow the 3rd div to scroll i get some aweful lags and touch responsivness is weird. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<body style="overflow:hidden">
 <div>
    BLA1
 </div>
 <div>
   BLA2
 </div>
 <div style="overflow: auto;">
    BLA3 overflow is here
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just had a similar problem after updating from iOS 11 to iOS 12 and setting `position: fixed` on the `body` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the iScroll4 plugin I got a new trick for iPad Web Developpers.
Apparently it works way better with this CSS :

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden; 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

While this lag like hell :

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep elements positioned absolute or relative from disappearing for a second or two when scrolling with this approach?

Comment: @jasonmerino it's a known issue with fixed elt scrolling. You could override the CSS of the elements right after the scroll. never tried though. if you find please comment here

Comment: This worked great! Just a quick note, that I only had to use the -webkit-overflow-scrolling property, while leaving overflow: auto.

Comment: @fanfavorite yes, the webkit part is the important one although is always good to specify which axis allows overflowing...

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more.  You just made my day five times over.  The difference when adding `overflow-x: hidden` *versus* auto is just incredible.  I thought I'd never get the thing working right.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use iscroll 4 http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/ this will give best solution