# My page won't scroll on mobile/tablet (running on opencart)

Tags: mobile, iframe, scroll, lightbox

I have a site that has been built and a store has been recently added on top of it (built on the opencart platform). On the browsers I serve the cart through a lightbox and iFrame (colorbox) and it works well for that.

Site: http://www.gardenofflavor.com/ then click on "Shop" to see in the browser

But colorbox with iFrame doesn't function on iOS properly (see iFrame thread about mobile (iOS6 seems to have made this worse: [how to properly display an iFrame in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267996/how-to-properly-display-an-iframe-in-mobile-safari/5359546#5359546) ) so I can't serve the same content to mobile users.

I'm thinking about serving a direct link for mobile users as a temporary fix, doesn't look the best but I need this to function.

Mobile/tablet users would link directly into the store (for example): https://shop.gardenofflavor.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=59

The problem I'm having is that the page won't scroll in mobile. I've checked for absolute positioning related to the overall container and I don't find anything. I'm concerned there's something in the opencart js that plays funny with mobile, could that cause the problem?