# Whole pdf-file is not displayed through iframe in Mobile Safari on iPad 1/2

Tags: ipad, pdf, mobile, iframe, safari

I have faced a pretty strange issue. I'm trying to display pdf files using iframe. Little documents, consisting of 1-2 pages, are displayed correctly. But when it comes to documents consisting of for example 5 "heavy" pages, the iframe doesn't display the whole document - the document is cropped and as a result about 2-3 pages are displayed only.

Below is my code. As you can see it's pretty straightforward.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing iFrames on iPad</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no" src="https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/SafariWebContent.pdf" />
</body>
```

Can anyone help me to find out what is the reason for such strange behavior?

Comment: 1) is this being done on Safari on an iPad? 2) Is there a requirement that the PDF be shown in an iframe? 3) what is the reason for scrolling="no" on your iframe tag?

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand iframe's height is what's responsible for the page cutting off, as you're actually scrolling the frame, and not the pdf inside the frame (i.e. setting height to "400%" will potentially give you the space you need, but it's sloppy).
This solution uses JavaScript to scroll the pdf contents itself, and may help:
[how to properly display an iFrame in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267996/how-to-properly-display-an-iframe-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: I liked the sloppy yet working solution of increasing the iframe height to something like 400%. It's been a day searching for the right solution for iframe pdf in mobile safari browser and this is the quickest nice little fix.