# html + content spills out of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe and content inside it. In my IOS mobile safari browser, the content, instead of scrolling inside the iframe, spills out. It works fine for desktop version of the browser. Why does it spill for the mobile safari browser. The iframe is defined in following manner:

```
<iframe height='100px' width='650px' frameborder=0 src='/tandc.php#2'></iframe>
```

What kind of property changes we can make to fix this bug? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using any css ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that will solve your problem, but worth a try.

Try @Case solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267996/how-to-properly-display-an-iframe-in-mobile-safari) and see what happen.