# Submit a form embedded in an iFrame does not work in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, iframe, mobile-safari, p3p

In a website with `mydomain.tld`, an iFrame containing a form that is hosted on `otherdomain.tld` is embedded. Both sites are non-SSL running on port 80.

Now, this form won't submit on iPhone 5 running on iOS 7. I can reproduce it in the iOS-Simulator when choosing "iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)" (doesn't happen with "4-inch" only).

The submit event is triggered (at least if I catch it via JavaScript) but no request is made according to the developer tools.

If I open the iFrame source directly, the form will submit.

I had a similar problem with Internet Explorer and learned about [P3P](http://www.w3.org/P3P/) and could solve the problems sending a special P3P header:

```
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"
```

But for the problem mentioned with Safari this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Are there any known restrictions regarding Safari and forms in iFrames?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667785/iframe-and-mobile-safari-ipad-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've found out, the problem was related to using cookies in iFrames which triggered the Spamshield of the form in the iFrame to block the form submission.

Since it's an opt-in form, I deactivated the Spamshield, but I've found a solution (which I didn't test) that should make cookies work by a submit to a hidden form that is triggered on loading the iFrame content.

> ```
> <script>   window.setTimeout(function() {
> if (document.cookie.indexOf('test_cookie=1') < 0) {
>   var      
>     name = 'test_cookie',
>     div = document.getElementById(name),
>     iframe = document.createElement('iframe'),
>     form = document.createElement('form');
>
>   iframe.name = name;
>   iframe.src = 'javascript:false';
>   div.appendChild(iframe);
>
>   form.action = location.toString();
>   form.method = 'POST';
>   form.target = name;
>   div.appendChild(form);
>
>   form.submit();
> }   }, 10); </script>
> ```

Source: https://gist.github.com/daaku/586182

Answer (score 0):

IOS devices change numbers to anchor links with href="tel:xxxxx" and mess up json data
http://xatzis.com/2014/03/29/submitting-forms-iframes-ios-devices/