# Scroll iframe on iPhone doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I know that are many examples showing this problem, but I tried everything and my iframe doesn't scroll on iPhone.

I have this code:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="header"><div>
   <div id="container_iframe">
       <iframe id ="external_content_iframe"></iframe>
   </div>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
#container_iframe
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 88%;
    z-index: 1001;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 55px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y:scroll !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
}

#external_content_iframe
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1001;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top:15%;
}
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: what do you mean scroll your iframe? Like allowing scrolling in iframe?

Comment: Yes , allowing scrolling the content of iframe

Comment: Bit odd really, you probably don't need to set overflow on the div container, the iframe should host it's own scrollbar if it is necessary. It's also possible that you have to set body and div.content to 100% height, so your containers could actually calculate the heights.

Comment: I noticed that works in IOS 7 but in IOS8 doesn't scroll.

Comment: I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046373/iframe-scrolling-ios-8 with the same problem, but with no solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer to these Questions, They may have the answer/explanation you're looking for:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599153/iframes-and-the-safari-on-the-ipad-how-can-the-user-scroll-the-content)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667785/iframe-and-mobile-safari-ipad-iphone)