# Adjust height of iframe when new content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iFrame that is included in my HTML and is available when the page loads. When the page first loads, the iFrame has no content/src. I am using jQuery to insert content into the iFrame dynamically. When a user clicks a link on my page, the contents of the iFrame are updated. All of this is working for me.

However, I am struggling to adjust the height of the iFrame when new content is loaded. I have tried several solutions on Stack Overflow but with no success. Here is my iFrame code:

`<iframe id="myframe" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Here is my jQuery that changes the HTML inside of my iFrame:

`emailOpened.find('#myframe').contents().find('body').html(email.body);`

This works for me. I just need my iFrame to adjust its height based on the height of the content being injected. I have failed on all attempts with this part.

### Update

Here is my new HTML:

```
<iframe id="myframe" width="100%" frameborder="0">
  <body onload="parent.resizeIframe(document.body.scrollHeight);">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking `emailOpened.find('#myframe').contents().find('body').height()` ? Otherwise you could have something that runs in the iframe (javascript of some kind) that posts the inner height at some interval and the outer code could respond. `postMessage` or direct access would work for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need mobile support and allow (user) scrolling for the iframe check out https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer a as drop-in solution which fixes different issues on iOS and android.

- [how to properly display an iFrame in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267996/how-to-properly-display-an-iframe-in-mobile-safari)
- https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=iframe+resize+ios+issue

I had to support mobile devices as well and ended up using it after some hours of research and testing. I've also used the provided message channel to send messages to the inner document back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function directly after the html has been changed.

```
      function resizeIframe() {
          var newHeight = document.getElementById('myframe').contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
          document.getElementById('myframe').style.height = parseInt(newHeight,10) + 10 + 'px';
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try this now. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @three3 I forgot to put in the actual function. I just added it. Make sure you have that.

Comment: Thank you, just noticed that. I am adding that now. And just to be clear, do I add the `parent.resizeIframe(document.body.scrollHeight);` to the `onload` attribute of the iFrame?

Comment: @three3 No, you put it in the onload of the actual page inside of the iframe. That's why it is calling the parent. You won't be able to have it in the onload unless the content is changed before the page is loaded. I recommend just putting `parent.resizeIframe(document.body.scrollHeight);` in a function and calling it when your jquery script has ran.

Comment: I have updated my original posting with the new iFrame HTML. Is this correct? If so, it did not work for me. The height does not adjust. I have a feeling I am doing something wrong here. Any extra help is appreciated!

Comment: @three3 I guess I was confused on what you were doing. I thought you were actually loading the iframe. Try my new answer, itl fit your needs more.

Comment: I will give this a try. I am not by my computer, but I will be back in about 20 minutes. Fingers crossed this works for me! Thanks

Comment: may have cross domain issue,  error "Blocked a frame with origin "https://otherOrigin.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Comment: @lannyf you can only control iframe content if the domains are the same as the original page that loaded them