# iPad Frame scroll issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, safari

I am trying to display a PDF in an iframe..So there are 2 frames and the bottom frame has the pdf. It is coded as;

```
<frame src="ebook.pdf" title="Content Frame" name="content" id="content" frameborder="0" border="0" noresize scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresizescrolling="AUTO" framespacing="0" />
```

For some reason, I am unable to scroll through the PDF in iPad Safari...More specifically within the iframe..

Is this a PDF issue or is it an iframe issue?

I have tried the using the  instead of frame..Still does not work..

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate [IFRAMEs and the Safari on the iPad, how can the user scroll the content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599153/iframes-and-the-safari-on-the-ipad-how-can-the-user-scroll-the-content)

Comment: Yes, I saw the link..But it does not provide any help. I am still looking for a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Vik..Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: No. I have an iPad and can't scroll certain internal frames on websites.

Comment: So how can we fix the frame scroll issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling within frames is a tricky UX thing with the iPad -- try scrolling with two fingers.  I don't know about PDFs, but that's how scrolling is done for other frames in Safari.

Comment: I tried scrolling with 2 fingers..still does not scroll or go to the next page...

Comment: Just to add, I can scroll through the pdf if I hit the complete PDF URL directly in Safari..However the pdf is actually displayed within an iframe in my app and I cannot scroll through that in the iframe..

Comment: If you give a link to the full page with code, maybe someone can help.  But, if the duplicate question link or my answer didn't help, you might be out of luck

Comment: You can checkout the page on http://ipad.atwebpages.com/test.html
Again Works fine on desktop...does not scroll on iPad..

Comment: @testndtv if jn_pdx's answer didn't help you, why did you accept it? I have the same problem and I would like to have an answer too...

Answer (score 1):

[Heres a link](http://berkey.biz/nwpb/photos/blog/blog.html) to an iframe that doesnt scroll on the ipad:

I have to redesign all my pages in iWeb now since the iPad won't scroll iFrames made with iWeb on my iPad. I get quite a few hits from people using iOS.

Comment: So how r u going to redesign?

Answer (score 1):

When you insert the `<iframe>` into a `<div>` with height specification and set `overflow-y` to scroll (maybe `auto` i did'nt try) you can scroll using two fingers on iPad. It has no effect on pc browsers.

Comment: It works, but mess up on pc/crome - double scrolling. But that's an easy fix, and it actually works, slow, but works on the !"#¤ ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Use (iOS App) Opera Mini browser instead, when clicking on a pdf in Opera Mini it induces Safari to open the PDF in a non-frame mode. Weird I know but it works.

Comment: User is asking about how to prevent that behavior on his website, not just for himself.