# scroll iframe on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IFRAMEs and the Safari on the iPad, how can the user scroll the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599153/iframes-and-the-safari-on-the-ipad-how-can-the-user-scroll-the-content)

I have a page which has a code roughly like follow;

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<iframe src="grid_data.html" width="100%" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now the grid_data.html has tabular data of many rows/columns and is part of the main page...

While this grid scrolls horizontally within the main page on desktop browsers like IE/FF, I cannot get it to scroll on the iPad Safari..
i.e. it actually displays the complete grid data without any scroll bars..

I tried experimenting with overflow:auto for the iframe, but still hasn't helped..

How do I get the grid data (part of iframe) to scroll on the iPad?

To get a rough idea, you can see the page on http://ipad.atwebpages.com/table/try.html
Just imagine there are multiple date columns like 05/24/2011 , 05/23/2011 , 05/22/2011 , 05/21/2011 and so on...

Comment: Yes but the solution given is not working...

Comment: Then I would suggest solving your use case in another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599153/iframes-and-the-safari-on-the-ipad-how-can-the-user-scroll-the-content), with its comments.

From the comments:

> Unfortunately this doesn't work
>   either. It seems that two fingered
>   iframe and object scrolling broke in
>   4.2.1 (although it works for textboxes). Hopefully Apple will fix
>   this annoying bug in the next release.
>   – user357320 Jan 7 at 10:51

Comment: The answers given in the other question do not seem to work on the ipad latest os...do u have ref to any working example?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that iframes display and scroll properly. You can use an object tag to replace an iframe and the contents will be scrollable with 2 fingers.

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <object id="object" width="100%" type="text/html" data="grid_data.html"></object>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```