# iframe scroll not in iPad safari

Tags: ipad, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe, ios7, extjs4.2

Am using extjs 4.2.2 and the iframe doesn't show scroll only in iPad safari.
I went through [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128184/scroll-iframe-on-ipad)

I have tried with the style "overflow:scroll !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;" but in vain.

Is there fix for this issue in ios 7.1.