# How to scroll an iframe inside another iframe with iPhone or iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, iframe, scroll, touch

I'm creating a website with iWeb. I use some iframes on my web and I want to be abble to scroll the content with touch devices too, like iPhone or iPad.

I have found a solution on this question ( [IFRAMEs and the Safari on the iPad, how can the user scroll the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599153/iframes-and-the-safari-on-the-ipad-how-can-the-user-scroll-the-content) ) using this script ( https://gist.github.com/2388015 ).

It works, but I've found another problem. When the iframe to scroll is inside another iframe, it does not work propertly all the times. Sometimes it's possible to scroll it fine with one finger on iPad or iPhone, but sometimes not.

I created a TEST page to show you how it works:

http://www.davidpratsjuan.com/TESTS

Please, try it and if you know what is exactly the problem and how to solve it, tell me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?