# Scroll iframe using buttons - iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, iframe

I'm creating the website where content is dynamically added using iframe (files of iframes are on the same server). Loaded iframe has buttons to scroll iframe content but I can't find a reason why it doesn't work on iPhone - it works well using Android. Here is the code I used:

```
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){     
            var element = $(this).attr('data-scroll');      
            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.page[data-bookmarks=' + element + ']').offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });
```

Btw. click event works well, because I checked it using alert. Simply scrollTop seems doesn't work on iOS devices.

Comment: A jsfiddle demo with your html will be helpful

Comment: try with -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch on your code

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ziggy try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599153/iframes-and-the-safari-on-the-ipad-how-can-the-user-scroll-the-content

Comment: Yes, I checked it, but the problem is that I'm trying to scroll using buttons, scrolling using fingers works well.

Comment: @Ziggy when you press the button. you want to scroll the page ah

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not sure, maybe iOS isn't prepared for scrolling iframes using button but maybe there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found several links that might solve this issue, but the one that I ran into the most was this:

> It's much easier to control overflowed divs than it is `iFrames`, and the scrolling + blank content issues are working all the way back to iOS 4, where previously I wasn't even able to get the 2 finger scrolling to work (in `iFrames`).
>
> It goes something like this:
>
> `<iframe id="example-iframe" width="600" height="200" src="a-file.html"></iframe>`
>
> a-file.html:
>
> ```
> <html>
> <body>
> <div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
> ...
> </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

### Other Links

- [-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch does not "obey" z-index](https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/14)
- [iFrame scrolling doesn't work on an iPhone](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19780024#19780024)
- [iFrame scrolling on an iOS device](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/2#issuecomment-5997068)
- [dropdown-menu problems with -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch on the iPad](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3663)