# iFrame modal scrolling on ipad/iphone

Tags: ios, css, iframe, scroll, modal-dialog

I'm working on a project on which I'm creating a modal. Basically, I have an overlay with `position: fixed;` The overlay contains an iFrame with the content of the modal. The iFrame can vary in height and when it does not fit the viewport the content gets cut off. Furthermore, when I scroll in the modal the only thing that scrolls is the background layer behind the overlay.

You are supposed to be able to scroll down in the iframe without the background layer moves. How can I achieve this?

Everything works fine in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and even in IE8. However, the issue only appears on iPad/iPhone.

You can see a working demo of the issue here: http://mcash.dk/dev/overlay/

Comment: I get your problems too and I have yet to come up with a solution. The main issue is that iOS 4.3 onwards force iframes to use the full height of the web page, rendering css's percentage values useless and modals to either be at 50% of the page or right at the top where users might have already scrolled pass. 

What we can do is to check how to identify which portion of the web page the user is viewing (E.g. 300px down) add half the height of the page to the modal, top: (300+window.height()/2)px; However, i suspect that window.height() returns the entire height of the webpage.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you need to enclose the iframe in a container div and then style the container with

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch
```

Read more here:

[IFRAMEs and the Safari on the iPad, how can the user scroll the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599153/iframes-and-the-safari-on-the-ipad-how-can-the-user-scroll-the-content)