# Scrolling iframe/div on Ios

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, scroll

OK, so I have searched and searched and tried multiple suggestions, but I just can't get this thing to work.

I have a site: http://ophwork.com/testv3/index_testv3.html

It's very much hacked together as I've been learning how to do each thing I want. It's also very much a work in progress, with dead links and content scattered about. Many apologies if this hurts your head.

Basically it's doing everything I want it to on Desktop, various browsers, Mac PC and Android. BUT the divs/iframes won't scroll on iOS and I can't for the life of me fix it.

Anybody got any ideas?

Ultimately I know I need to sit down and rebuild the site from scratch as it's frankly a mess. But for now I would like to see if anybody can work out what's causing this.

Comment: Try this CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599153/iframes-and-the-safari-on-the-ipad-how-can-the-user-scroll-the-content

Comment: Thank you for this.  had seen this conversation before, but none of the suggestions seem to work, or they break other things.

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch fixed my reportViewer's iframe scroll on iPad. May be you should try to place it in other div's style.

Comment: Thank you also - unless I'm being really dumb and doing it wrong, I have tried adding this to every possible div in every possible combination - still nothing. Pulling my hair out here.